# Programmatically Query SP Image Library?

Tags: ajax, sharepoint

How do I query SharePoint (MOSS 2007) image library from an AJAX web part? I'm building this web part from scratch and was advised to use SP object model since I can develop on a dev server with VS2010.

The web part will untimatelly display images

Comment: Risho, did I answer your question?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty broad question so I'll try to hit some of the high level challenges.

### Setup

If you want to use AJAX with SP 2007, you'll have some setup to do. You'll need to setup your web.config to allow AJAX at all so I'd recommend checking out the AJAX.config feature that is a part of http://features.codeplex.com/. You might want to consider using `Version=3.5.0.0` instead of 1.0.

Once you have AJAX enabled, you'll need a `ScriptManager` somewhere on your page. The easiest way to do this is just use SharePoint Designer to add it to the site's masterpage.

```
<WebPartPages:SPWebPartManager id="m" runat="Server"/>
<asp:ScriptManager EnableHistory="true" EnableSecureHistoryState="false" runat="server" ID="ScriptManager1"></asp:ScriptManager>
```

Alternatively, the "best" way is to probably create a new AJAX enabled masterpage you deploy as part of your solution.

### Code

Now that your ScriptManager is somewhere on the page, you'll be able to get it inside your webpart like so:

```
ScriptManager currentScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page);
```

Next, you'll need all of your controls that will be updated via ajax inside an `UpdatePanel`. If you're using 2010, I think it will probably create a visual web part for you so you'll probably have this in your ASCX (I'm using 2008 so it will probably be slightly different):

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnRollDice" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblRollMessage" Text="Click the button to roll the dice!" />
        <asp:Label runat="server" ID="lblCurrentTime" Text="[Current time goes here]" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>

<asp:Button ID="btnRollDice" runat="server" Text="Roll the Dice!" />
```

Finally, you'll be able to start querying the SharePoint Images library using the SharePoint object model. You can get the current web:

```
SPWeb web = SPControl.GetContextWeb(this.Context);
```

Then, get your images library, and query using SPList.GetItems. Here is an example against a Tasks list: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx

Comment: If you're using VS2010 to build SP2007 web parts, I would also recommend reading this article: http://msadvisor.wordpress.com/2010/05/23/build-a-sharepoint-2007-web-part-with-a-visual-studio-2010-visual-web-part-project/. Mainly it involves swapping out `Microsoft.SharePoint` DLL references and tweaking a few other parts that are looking specifically for version 14 of SP instead of 12.